# Superuser app won't grant root acess anymore

Tags: applications, root-access, superuser

I tried to do a backup a few days ago but TB just stucked on the "Asking root permissions" screen. And now, every app that needs root access doesn't work properly because root access is denied. My superuser app is updated, and I also tried to reset its user data but it's still not working. Does anyone have an idea to make it work again ?

EDIT

Here's the logcat :

```
07-09 18:28:21.552 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:24.554 W/PowerManagerService( 2940): Timer 0x3->0x3|0x0
07-09 18:28:24.627 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:24.632 V/lights  ( 2940): set_light_buttons invoked
07-09 18:28:24.632 D/lights  ( 2940): set_light_button on=255
07-09 18:28:24.632 I/PowerManagerService( 2940): Ulight 3->7|0
07-09 18:28:24.817 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:24.847 I/ActivityManager( 2940): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.fede.launcher/.Launcher }
07-09 18:28:25.077 D/PhoneWindow( 6377): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view android.widget.LinearLayout@47242a48 has no id.
07-09 18:28:26.047 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:26.047 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:26.052 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:26.272 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:26.272 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:26.272 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:27.347 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:27.347 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:27.352 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:27.667 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:27.672 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:27.672 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:28.482 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:28.482 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:28.482 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:29.082 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:29.082 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:29.082 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:29.702 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:29.702 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:29.707 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:30.382 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:30.382 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:30.392 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:30.777 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:30.777 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:30.787 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:30.877 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:30.882 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:30.887 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473bdba0 com.fede.launcher/com.fede.launcher.Launcher paused=false}
07-09 18:28:31.017 I/ActivityManager( 2940): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/.MainActivity }
07-09 18:28:31.067 I/ActivityManager( 2940): Start proc com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup for activity com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/.MainActivity: pid=6434 uid=10051 gids={1015, 3003}
07-09 18:28:31.227 I/Zygote  ( 6434): Zygote: pid 6434 has INTERNET permission, then set capability for CAP_NET_RAW
07-09 18:28:31.502 I/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainApplication( 6434): onCreate()
07-09 18:28:32.947 I/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainApplication( 6434): Detected CPU architecture: ARM
07-09 18:28:32.962 W/Settings( 6434): Setting android_id has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Secure, returning read-only value.
07-09 18:28:32.967 D/o.䁄   ( 6434): Debug features are disabled.
07-09 18:28:33.002 I/o.쮱   ( 6434): restoreMySettings_ifNeeded()
07-09 18:28:33.047 I/o.쮱   ( 6434): Internal settings found => No need to restore.
07-09 18:28:33.647 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x0 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:33.717 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x0 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:33.782 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x0 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:33.792 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0xf a=-1}
07-09 18:28:33.872 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x80 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:33.872 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:34.142 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x20 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:34.207 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x1 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:34.267 W/Resources( 6434): Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x3 a=-1}
07-09 18:28:34.557 I/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.MainActivity( 6434): Main Activity is being created for the first time => scheduling next wake-up ...
07-09 18:28:34.567 I/o.յ    ( 6434): scheduleNextWakeup(): Invoked with idToExcludeForToday=null
07-09 18:28:34.692 I/o.յ    ( 6434): scheduleNextWakeup(): No next wakeup scheduled.
07-09 18:28:34.707 I/o.ᡝ   ( 6434): Thread started.
07-09 18:28:35.177 W/PowerManagerService( 2940): Timer 0x7->0x3|0x0
07-09 18:28:35.177 V/lights  ( 2940): set_light_buttons invoked
07-09 18:28:35.177 D/lights  ( 2940): set_light_button on=0
07-09 18:28:35.177 I/PowerManagerService( 2940): Ulight 7->3|0
07-09 18:28:36.282 I/o.嫶   ( 6434): Detected 0 mount point(s) in addition to Android "external" storage.
07-09 18:28:36.292 I/ActivityManager( 2940): Displayed activity com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/.MainActivity: 5242 ms (total 5242 ms)
07-09 18:28:36.307 I/o.䌮   ( 6434): [Licensing] No cache file: /mnt/sdcard/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/licensing-cache.xml
07-09 18:28:36.307 I/o.䌮   ( 6434): [Licensing] Cache valid? = false
07-09 18:28:36.307 I/o.䌮   ( 6434): [Licensing] Deleting non-valid cache file: /mnt/sdcard/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/licensing-cache.xml
07-09 18:28:36.397 I/o.嫶   ( 6434): Detected 0 mount point(s) in addition to Android "external" storage.
07-09 18:28:36.407 W/System.err( 6434): ERROR: Could not open license file: /data/data/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup/files/license.txt
07-09 18:28:36.512 E/su      ( 6447): sudb - Opening database
07-09 18:28:36.517 E/su      ( 6447): Couldn't open database: unable to open database file
07-09 18:28:36.517 E/su      ( 6447): sudb - Could not open database, prompt user
07-09 18:28:37.332 D/AndroidRuntime( 6449): 
07-09 18:28:37.332 D/AndroidRuntime( 6449): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
07-09 18:28:37.332 D/AndroidRuntime( 6449): CheckJNI is OFF
07-09 18:28:37.337 E/AndroidRuntime( 6449): /system/csc/customer.xml ==> cannot open file
07-09 18:28:37.342 D/AndroidRuntime( 6449): found sales_code tag = <>, </> 
07-09 18:28:37.342 E/AndroidRuntime( 6449): /system/csc/feature.xml ==> cannot open file
07-09 18:28:37.747 D/AndroidRuntime( 6449): --- registering native functions ---
07-09 18:28:38.132 D/LibQmg_native( 6449): register_android_app_LibQmg
07-09 18:28:43.737 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:43.737 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:43.742 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4732a058 StatusBar paused=false}
07-09 18:28:43.922 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:43.927 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:43.947 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4732a058 StatusBar paused=false}
07-09 18:28:46.087 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:46.087 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:46.092 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4739b5f8 TrackingView paused=false}
07-09 18:28:46.242 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:46.247 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:46.252 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4739b5f8 TrackingView paused=false}
07-09 18:28:46.537 W/InputManagerService( 2940): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@470d25d0
07-09 18:28:47.879 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:47.882 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:47.892 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4732a058 StatusBar paused=false}
07-09 18:28:48.087 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:48.092 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:48.097 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{4732a058 StatusBar paused=false}
07-09 18:28:48.617 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:48.622 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473baca0 StatusBarExpanded paused=false}
07-09 18:28:48.622 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Dn(0=>1)
07-09 18:28:48.747 I/KeyInputQueue( 2940): Input event
07-09 18:28:48.747 V/WindowManager( 2940): Dsptch > Window{473baca0 StatusBarExpanded paused=false}
07-09 18:28:48.747 V/InputDevice( 2940): ID[0]=0(0) Up(1=>0)
07-09 18:28:49.032 W/InputManagerService( 2940): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46fc9070
```

Comment: First things first. Is your phone still rooted? Search Google Play for apps that will "check root".

Comment: @geffchang I installed a "Root check" app but the apps processes again and again and it never stops.

Comment: What android version? What version of TB are you using?

Comment: @t0mm13b My Android version is 2.2 and I've got TB 4.6.7

Comment: Try upgrading TB, latest is 6.0.5.1.... I can clearly remember the older TB versions would get stuck in endless loop waiting for SU permissions approval. Are you using the *pro* version or *donate* version?

Comment: @t0mm13b Installed the last version of TB from Play Store, still stuck on the "Asking root access" screen.

Comment: Please enclose the logcat to ascertain what is happening that is contributing to the "Asking for root access".. :)

Comment: @t0mm13b Done !

Comment: @geffchang Check root completed, still rooted.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few scenarios that might explain what's going on.

### Superuser app binaries need to be updated

Open your Superuser app and check for any updates to the binaries. The binary is what gives that Superuser app the right to grant or deny other apps superuser priviliges. If it is outdated or has been replaced by a different binary, you may need to update it to get it working again.

### Root priviliges denied permanently for the app

When an app requests superuser access, a Superuser app generally prompts the user to `Allow` or `Deny`. Usually, it also gives the option to follow the same action temporarily, for a set time, or permanently (depending on the Superuser app you use).

If you deny an app root privileges permanently, it will likely cause the app to pause when asking the system for root privileges until it times out. Check your Superuser app to make sure Titanium Backup isn't marked as deny.

### Lack Root

You may have lost root access (possibly during an automatic Over The Air update), which would be why the app requesting superuser rights is failing. Most Superuser apps display a `toast` or other message anytime an app requests root privileges (along with whether that request was granted or denied).

### Alternate Superuser App

Another Superuser app may have been installed to take over requests for sudo access. If you know you have root, check for other Superuser apps. They usually have "Super" in them, though this is not a guarantee.

### Very slow device

On my old phone, there would be times when the CPU was bogged down (ex right after bootup). If I tried to open a root app, it would ask for root rights, then time out before the Superuser app could process the request.

This usually only happened for an app that caused a prompt to allow or deny, but it still happened on occasion with apps that had been granted access forever.

Comment: I tried to update the binaries but at the end of the process the app asks for root access and it's denied, of course. I reset superuser's user data so there's no more permanent denied app. I'm trying to root check but the process takes forever and seems to be on an infinite loop. I didn't installed any other superuser app. My phone is very slow, but I don't think this is the cause.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this which caught my eye:

```
07-09 18:28:36.512 E/su      ( 6447): sudb - Opening database 
07-09 18:28:36.517 E/su      ( 6447): Couldn't open database: unable to open database file 
07-09 18:28:36.517 E/su      ( 6447): sudb - Could not open database, prompt user`
```

Sounds like a botched install of the SuperUser app in itself. Where did you get the app from as matter of curiousity?

Thing is, there's two versions of superuser apps and are not interchangeable, its either one app or the other, both mutually exclusive.

- One by [Koushik Dutta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser&hl=en) and
- One by [Noshufou](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su&hl=en)

I'd be more inclined to think that this particular one was a mix 'n' match version. Try downloading the "proper" version either on the play store.

Comment: I've got Noshufou's one but since it's in the default apps of my ROM I can't uninstall it.

Answer (score -1):

If its on the default apps of your phone, go to google play store and download root explorer, from there, prese the buttons befote the micro sd card simbol, then locate and press app/system apps, find superuser and delete it from the internal phone.